# How do I pinpoint a variable in a vector by a corresponding value?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and this is definitely a beginner question but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it looking at other questions on here - I have a vector with a row of years and a row of values: [image: Example vector]

Is there any way to pinpoint to a specific value by year? I know I can extract a specific value by its coordinates through vector[x,y], but is there any way to do that to extract the value of y where x="1900" for example?

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `mydata`, `mydata$population.size[mydata$Year==1900]`. Also it looks like you have a data frame rather than a vector (a vector is one-dimensional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SamR also said in the comments you can use the following code. First I created your data with the year `1900` added as an example to show:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1901, 1906, 1911, 1916, 1921, 1900),
                 population.size = c(45549, 50310, 52722, 52998, 56988, 57291))

df$population.size[df$Year==1900]
```

Output:

```
[1] 57291
```